# How to update ListFragment on Runtime

Tags: android, fragment, android-listfragment

I am developing an app in which there are three pan layout with fragments and each fragments are `ListFragment`. I am communicating between them via `interface` successfully but I am not able to update the `ListView` with new items. Here is my code of the `ListView` which need to be updated:

```
public class SubChaptersListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    public interface OnSubChapterSelectListener {
        public void onSubChapterSelected(int position);
    }

        @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mAdapter = null;
}

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.sub_sub_category_fragment) != null) {
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
    }

        // this function will be invoked from another fragment (succesffully invoked)
    public void updateList(int position) {
        Log.d("success", "" + position); // position is successfully passed
        int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ? android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1
                : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
//      Chapter instance = CompetitiveProgramming.chapterList.get(position);
        for (int i = 0; i < CompetitiveProgramming.chapterList.get(position).subchapterList.size(); i++) {
            items.add(CompetitiveProgramming.chapterList.get(position).subchapterList.get(i).subChapterTitle);
        }
                // everything is okay till now
                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSherlockActivity(), layout, items)); // is not working in this line and crashed
    }
}
```

How to update the `ListView` frequently in runtime?

Update:

```
public class SubChaptersListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
    OnSubChapterSelectListener mCallback; 
    public interface OnSubChapterSelectListener {
        public void onSubChapterSelected(int prev, int position);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    int mPosition;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ? android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1
                : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
        Chapter instance = CompetitiveProgramming.chapterList.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < instance.subchapterList.size(); i++) {
            items.add(instance.subchapterList.get(i).subChapterTitle);
        }
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSherlockActivity(), layout, items);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.sub_sub_category_fragment) != null) {
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
    }

    public void updateList(int position) {
        mPosition = position;
        mAdapter.clear();
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < CompetitiveProgramming.chapterList.get(position).subchapterList.size(); i++) {
            items.add(CompetitiveProgramming.chapterList.get(position).subchapterList.get(i).subChapterTitle);
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        mCallback.onSubChapterSelected(mPosition, position);
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you post logcat

Comment: The errors are expected. `ListView` can't be updated dynamically like other widget. I need to get solution of how to refresh the `listFragment`.

Comment: Did you try notifyDatasetChanged method?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Actually I might misplaced it and did something wrong. Some complete code example on my code would be helpful :)

Comment: Wherever is your listview, just call it. If your list view la, la.notifiydatasetchanged(). Im on ipad i cant right complete code now sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
mAdapter.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < CompetitiveProgramming.chapterList.get(position).subchapterList.size(); i++) {
        mAdapter.add(CompetitiveProgramming.chapterList.get(position).subchapterList.get(i).subChapterTitle);
}
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: showing `NullPointerException` and runtime in `mAdapter.clear();` :(

Comment: Try creating a list adapter with empty data in the onCreate method for the SherlockListFragment first.

Comment: take a look at my upate. I have followed your instruction, nothing change :(

Comment: mAdapter is still null? Are you adding the fragment dynamically in the SherlockFragmentActivity, or are you adding it via XML?  Maybe check to make sure the onCreateActivity is being called.  Also, where are you calling updateList from?

Comment: from another fragment. And communicate via interface which is implemented by parent fragment. The communication is successful- I have checked it from `logcat`. I don't want to recreate the fragment, instead of I want to update the fragment's listview

Comment: Which fragment? I have provided the complete code of the corresponding child fragment

Comment: The code of the parent FragmentActivity (preferably where the child fragment is created and used).

Comment: This is the parent Fragment: http://pastebin.com/ZEY9HC6v
This is the xml Layout: http://pastebin.com/jjdtKDD5
This is ChapterListFragment: http://pastebin.com/ptcHK02E
This is SubChapterListFragment: http://pastebin.com/TKWwWkj6

Comment: Where's the parent FragmentActivity?

Comment: I solved my problem by creating `Fragment` instance globally and it is now available when I am calling `upateList()`. It was my mistake and I made ou in trouble. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Actually, looking at your onChapterSelected, onSubChapterSelected, onSubSubChapterSelected, why are you creating a new fragment each time?  These should be using the fragment objects you created from onPostExecute.  Perhaps consider storing those objects as member variables in the parent fragment, or looking them up via the fragment manager.

Answer (score 1):

After feeding data through adapter, you need to call **mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();** 
It should update then..

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you give me some complete code example upon my code?

Comment: May be you can try something like this:  ArrayAdapter mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSherlockActivity(), layout, items)); setListAdapter(mAdapter); mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: in where I need to invoke `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` ? in `updateList()` on everytime I clicked to update the list? or in `onActivityCreated()`?

Comment: As the name suggests, you need to call this when ever you need to update your dataset. So, you may call everytime you click to update the list

Comment: showing `NullPointerException` and runtime in `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` :(

Comment: from where do you call your updateList()? Is it called before mAdapter is assigned as you are saying that your mAdapter is NULL.

Comment: This is the parent Fragment: http://pastebin.com/ZEY9HC6v
This is the xml Layout: http://pastebin.com/jjdtKDD5
This is ChapterListFragment: http://pastebin.com/ptcHK02E
This is SubChapterListFragment: http://pastebin.com/TKWwWkj6